# Unable to update the day and night modes in android with window manager screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

with WindowManager I am displaying one layout. If I try to change night or day mode it's not effecting. My requirement is if I click on window manager view it should change day mode and vice versa

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
 var view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.child_layout,null)
 windowManager.addView(view,params)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue too (with an InputMethodService inflating a keyboard view). I don't know if there's a better way to fix it but this was my workaround:

I created an explicit day theme and night theme alongside the DayNight theme. I used almost the same attributes in each one, but subclassed different themes (for the default theme my `parent` was `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar`, so for the other two I used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for the light theme and `Theme.AppCompat` for the dark theme). I also translated all the styles in `values-night` into attributes that could be set by the theme, so that the dark and light modes of my DayNight theme were identical to the other two that I had created.

I then used a `ContextThemeWrapper` with a theme according to my theme setting to inflate the view:

```
val themeSetting = getStringPref(R.string.themeSettingKey)
val themeId = if (themeSetting == "MODE_NIGHT_NO") {
    R.style.AppThemeLight
} else if (themeSetting == "MODE_NIGHT_YES") {
    R.style.AppThemeDark
} else {  // MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
    R.style.AppTheme
}
val wrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeId)
LayoutInflater.from(wrapper).inflate(...)
```

This unfortunately means the theme is only set when the layout is inflated. If the theme setting somehow changes when the view is still open, the theme won't update. (If the setting is `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`, it will still dynamically adjust to the system's theme setting).

Since I'm using an `InputMethodService`, I added this method to restart the keyboard view whenever it's shown: (this doesn't have a noticeable performance impact per my testing)

```
override fun onStartInputView(info: EditorInfo, restarting: Boolean) {
    setInputView(onCreateInputView())
}
```

With a `WindowManager` you'd probably want to restart the window somehow. (As in, destroy the entire window and re-inflate the view). If that's not feasible, I have no idea what to do. I was stuck on this issue for two days.